# Splitting string on device control characters

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I need to process a file that looks like this:

þSome dataþþSome DataþþGEVA_BOD_000062þþGEVA_BOD_000119þ

I want to split the line of the file so that I can work with each data member independently. The problem is, I'm not sure how to work with "", which the internet tells me is "Device Control 4" (U+0014). How can I incorporate this character into a regex so that I can split the string properly? (þ|þþ) won't split the string at all.

Comment: `split("\u0014")` --- See Java Language Specification: [3.3. Unicode Escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3).

Comment: When I use that, I get this: �DATA� on every line.

Comment: Can you include the hex values of the characters of the string?

Comment: You get that because `þ` is `\u00FE`, aka [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN' (U+00FE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fe/index.htm), but you're printing the output in a code page where that character doesn't exist, so it gets replaced with `�`. It's a issue of the *printing*; the string is correct. If you're running in an IDE, tell it that output is UTF-8, and it'll print correctly.

Comment: Note however that it may also be that you're *reading* the file using the wrong code page, in which case the conversion from `þ` to `�` happens during the read, and the in-memory string will be wrong. You should spend some time studying articles on Java, Unicode and Code Pages.

Comment: I've set up my BufferedReader to take UTF-8 like so: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dat), "UTF-8"));, and I've set it up to split the string like so: line.split("(\u00FE|\u0014)");, but I'm still getting � where the thorns are.